# APEX to a STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-apex

could someone please help convert this apex query to oracle stored procedure? The part I don't understand is the if statement it doesnt return any values. Thanks

```
DECLARE
P_RESULT VARCHAR2(4000) ;
BEGIN

P_RESULT := 'SELECT /*+ RESULT_CACHE */  D.ORGANIZATION_NAME as ORG_NAME,
UDD.FS_STATEMENT_NUM FS_STATEMENT_NUM,(select DOC_DATE_TIME FROM U_DOCUMENT UD WHERE
UD.FS_STATEMENT_NUM = UUI.FS_STATEMENT_NUM AND UD.MISCELLANEOUS_NUM = ''0'') AS FILE_DATE, 

FROM U_DET D,
U_DOCUMENT_DET UDD,

where D.DET_TYPE=''O'' AND UDD.DET_NUM=D.DET_NUM
AND UDD.FS_STATEMENT_NUM=UUI.FS_STATEMENT_NUM
AND (UUI.MAT_DATE > ''' || to_date(local.pkg_bs_common.CHECK_FS_STATUS(:P5_DS_STATUS),'dd-mon-yyyy') || ''' OR UUI.MATURITY_DATE IS NULL)';

if :P5_ORGN_NAME is not null then 
P_RESULT := P_RESULT || ' AND (D.ORGANIZATION_NAME LIKE ''' || upper(:p5_ORGN_NAME) || '%'' OR D.FORMATTED_ORGANIZATION_NAME like
''' || local.pkg_bs_common.orgname_format(upper(:p5_ORGN_NAME)) || '%'')';
END IF;


--HTP.P(P_RESULT);
RETURN P_RESULT ;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `if :P5_ORGN_NAME is not null then`, the argument :P5_ORGN_NAME is a [bind variable](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html) for the page five item P5_ORGN_NAME session value. Which, running from apex, you'd pass as a parameter in the block definition.

If you need to call the procedure in a session context you can replace that line with either

`if (V('P5_ORGN_NAME') is not null) then`

or

`if (APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_STATE('P5_ORGN_NAME')) is not null then`

The same goes to every :P5_ORGN_NAME or :P5_DS_STATUS call in your code.

But before this you should wrap it all with:

```
if(APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.IS_SESSION_VALID) then
    /*your code here*/
end if;
```

To ensure that there's always a valid session.

[APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.IS_SESSION_VALID](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_auth.htm#AEAPI230)

[APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_STATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_util.htm#AEAPI151)